# Android Studios: Is it possible to filter json data based on user location?

Tags: android, json, filter, location

I am trying to develop an app which suggests places to eat based on the users location and the price of individual meals within those restaurants. I'm not quite sure how to go about doing this - I've considered using the Google Places API but that does not contain price information on individual meals. The other option is to construct my own database.

What is easiest method to filter data based on both location and my own fields (eg meal prices)?

Comment: By your own admission, you have no data. Hence, there is nothing to filter. Once you have a data source, you need to decide where that data will live (locally on the device? on a Web service that you create? on a third-party Web service? some combination of these?). Once you have those particulars determined, *then* starting to ask about filtering will make sense. As it stands, the answer varies widely: filtering data on-device in SQLite is radically different than providing filtering information to some third-party Web service. Get your data and its home first, then work from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all you can't filter json, you will filter where you will save data. you can do it by two ways :

1. you retrieve all the data from your database(advice use [firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/) easy to use) and filter the `list` or `array` or the `RecyclerView` where you save the data.
2. you send the conditions and retrieve the data to show them directly to your user